# what alternative of formdata in ios for web application?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, form-data, image-file

Because formdata function such as append, set etc. is not compatible in ios devices for web application, is there any alternative of formdata to upload image file to server? because the server need to get file.

Comment: I was trying to verify this information too. I was able to get FormData to work as I show here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59804038/